# Docker-compose expose Port on IPv6

Tags: docker, docker-compose, port, ipv6

I'm trying to run a docker Container with a number of exposed ports on IPv6. I don't want the containers to have IPv6 addresses of their own. All I want is for them to be reachable under the IPv6 address of the host (using port forwarding).

I enabled IPv6 in the docker daemon (http://docs.docker.oeynet.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/ipv6/).

I tried

```
ports:
  # The HTTP port
  - ":::80:80"
```

in the docker-compose.yaml for the container but that seems to mess up the configuration completely:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                  PORTS                                                                                  NAMES
9774a1a6322c   traefik:latest           "/entrypoint.sh --ap…"   1 second ago   Up Less than a second   80/tcp                                                                                 traefik
```

With another container (that is not under my control an I can't seem to find out how it's started), the ports were forwarded correctly:

```
a04b40299a8f   portainer/portainer-ce   "/portainer"             7 days ago     Up 3 minutes            0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, :::9000->9000/tcp   portainer
```

This one is also reachable using the IPv6 address of the host (as expected).
How can I achieve this for the first container?

Comment: IP, neither IPv4 nor IPv6, has ports. Ports are used by _some_ transport protocols, but IP has no idea about ports.

Comment: Have you looked at and enabled IPv6 with your docker daemon yet?
https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/

Comment: Yes, that's basically the same content as in the link in the post.

Comment: Somehow, in a newly installed environment (Docker v20.10.14), I'm able to expose ports via my host's IPv6 without doing anything. I'm not sure if it has something to do with me running Docker in rootless mode or if Docker developers fixed this.

Comment: it was a bug before `20.10.6` and the latest debian still has `20.10.5` in its repos: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-doesnt-open-ipv6-ports/106201/2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In short**

You have to manually select some ipv6 capable network in the `docker-compose.yml` file, for example:

```
services:
    serviceName:
        networks:
            - traefik

networks:
    traefik:
        enable_ipv6: true
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: "fd12:3456:789a:1::/64"
```

Be aware that some outdated `docker-compose` versions doesn't support `enable_ipv6` option. It is fixed somewhere between `1.26.2` (doesn't support) and `1.27.4` (does support).

**Explanation**

> When you start Docker, a default bridge network (also called bridge) is created automatically, and newly-started containers connect to it unless otherwise specified. [src](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/)

But when you use docker-compose it creates a network for you if you didn't specify one. Looks like that in the log:

> Creating network "traefik_default" with the default driver

And this default network hasn't ipv6 enabled:

```
$ docker network inspect traefik_default | grep EnableIPv6
    "EnableIPv6": false,
```

So, you should define a custom network with ipv6 enabled. Subnet parameter is mandatory if I am not mistaken and you can use some [private ipv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address) subnet like in my example above.

Be aware that the actual name of the network in my example will be `<projectName>_traefik`. You can create an external network instead with completely user-defined name (`traefik` in this case):

```
docker network create --ipv6 --subnet=fd12:3456:789a:2::/64 traefik
```

Comment: docker-compose doesn't seem to support the enable_ipv6 flag but creating the network manualls worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @MatthiasHolzapfel What do you mean by "doesn't seem to support the enable_ipv6 flag"? Do you mean in the docker-compose.yml "networks" section? What is config version of your docker-compose.yml then?

Comment: I made a little research and seems like it could be error in some versions of docker-compose before 1.28.1. There is PR that fixes that I believe https://github.com/docker/compose/commit/25d773c924b6337b63802c0d9649f800b542bf49
I have docker-compose 1.28.2 and enable_ipv6 works for me no matter of docker-compose.yml version (I tried 3-3.7).
What is your docker-compose version?

Comment: Looks like I'm bound to 1.21 for the moment. That explains it, thank you.

Comment: you just saved my day, have been using ipv6 (ISP only gives static v6 not v4) but couldnt hit the docker containers, however the server was easily pinged, your answer saved my day

Answer (score 6):

Quick addition here: the IPv6 syntax uses brackets `[::]`

```
ports:
  # The HTTP port
  - "[::]:80:80"
```